# Magento 2, filter product collection by sku while preserving the given array sequence

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection, sequence

Using below code, collection is filtered. If `$productSkus`  array is like

`Array ( [0] => 5714156000153 [1] => 8690604469871 [2] => 6412616365413 )`

after filtering I see the collection is in

`Array ( [0] => 8690604469871 [1] => 5714156000153 [2] => 6412616365413 )`

sequence. How to do filtering with respect to given sequence?

```
$collection ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $productSkus));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

```
  $collection ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $productSkus))
              ->addAttributeToSort('sku');
```

It defaults to ASC and use addAttributeToSort('sku', 'desc') for DESC.

Comment: I'm asking for a solution to keep the sequence of given array. Your solution is sorting desc or asc.

Comment: @Zinat did you find a solution for this to sort the products exactly as they are in the array?

Comment: @paj I had to keep a copy of original one, after filtering applied sorting based on that.

Comment: @zinat do you mean a copy of the original collection? Could you share your code with me please, I am struggling to achieve this. I am also losing the collection paging when I reorder it and see all products in the collection on the frontend.